# Split csv files based on time intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have exported wireshark pcap files to csv. I need to split these csv files based on time intervals. In the csv file there is a 'time' column. I would like to split these files into 1 sec time interval. So the first few packets arrived in the first 1 sec will get written to one file, next packets arrived in the next 1 sec into another file, so on. If the input file name is AAA.csv the split files will get the same name with a number attached to end. AAA1.csv,.....AAA5.csv so on. I am new to programming so not quite sure how to go forward from this point. Please help. Thanks  https://fil.email/8wSH9ohq

```
import os
startdir='.'
suffix='.csv'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startdir):
  for name in files:
    if name.endswith(suffix):
      filename=os.path.join(root,name)
```

---

Here is an extract of a csv file with rows from 2 consecutive seconds:

```
"No.","Time","Time delta from previous displayed frame","Length","Source","Destination","Protocol","Info"
"100","23:39:52.634388","0.000502000","28","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:1a (8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a) (TA)","Htc_9b:92:24 (ac:37:43:9b:92:24) (RA)","802.11","802.11 Block Ack, Flags=........"
"101","23:39:52.634393","0.000005000","102","Htc_9b:92:24","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:16","802.11","QoS Data, SN=45, FN=0, Flags=.p.....T"
"102","23:39:52.695277","0.060884000","28","Microsof_d2:8b:4f (30:59:b7:d2:8b:4f) (TA)","Sagemcom_28:38:64 (d0:6e:de:28:38:64) (RA)","802.11","802.11 Block Ack, Flags=........"
"103","23:39:52.695278","0.000001000","10","","Sagemcom_28:38:64 (d0:6e:de:28:38:64) (RA)","802.11","Clear-to-send, Flags=........"
"104","23:39:52.717845","0.022567000","16","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:1a (8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a) (TA)","Htc_9b:92:24 (ac:37:43:9b:92:24) (RA)","802.11","Request-to-send, Flags=........"
"105","23:39:52.717845","0.000000000","406","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:16","Htc_9b:92:24","802.11","QoS Data, SN=3446, FN=0, Flags=.p....F."
"106","23:39:52.717852","0.000007000","28","Htc_9b:92:24 (ac:37:43:9b:92:24) (TA)","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:1a (8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a) (RA)","802.11","802.11 Block Ack, Flags=........"
"107","23:39:52.717853","0.000001000","10","","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:1a (8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a) (RA)","802.11","Clear-to-send, Flags=........"
"108","23:39:52.719380","0.001527000","28","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:1a (8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a) (TA)","Htc_9b:92:24 (ac:37:43:9b:92:24) (RA)","802.11","802.11 Block Ack, Flags=........"
"109","23:39:52.719384","0.000004000","102","Htc_9b:92:24","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:16","802.11","QoS Data, SN=46, FN=0, Flags=.p.....T"
"110","23:39:52.719389","0.000005000","10","","Htc_9b:92:24 (ac:37:43:9b:92:24) (RA)","802.11","Clear-to-send, Flags=........"
"111","23:39:53.109091","0.389702000","24","Htc_9b:92:24","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:1a","802.11","Null function (No data), SN=4069, FN=0, Flags=...P...T"
"112","23:39:53.109586","0.000495000","10","","Htc_9b:92:24 (ac:37:43:9b:92:24) (RA)","802.11","Acknowledgement, Flags=........"
"113","23:39:53.149481","0.039895000","28","Sagemcom_28:38:64 (d0:6e:de:28:38:64) (TA)","Microsof_a0:a4:2c (58:82:a8:a0:a4:2c) (RA)","802.11","802.11 Block Ack, Flags=........"
"114","23:39:53.157218","0.007737000","24","Htc_9b:92:24","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:1a","802.11","Null function (No data), SN=4070, FN=0, Flags=.......T"
"115","23:39:53.159251","0.002033000","10","","Htc_9b:92:24 (ac:37:43:9b:92:24) (RA)","802.11","Acknowledgement, Flags=........"
"116","23:39:53.159252","0.000001000","16","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:1a (8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a) (TA)","Htc_9b:92:24 (ac:37:43:9b:92:24) (RA)","802.11","Request-to-send, Flags=........"
"117","23:39:53.159267","0.000015000","10","","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:1a (8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a) (RA)","802.11","Clear-to-send, Flags=........"
"118","23:39:53.160276","0.001009000","16","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:1a (8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a) (TA)","Htc_9b:92:24 (ac:37:43:9b:92:24) (RA)","802.11","Request-to-send, Flags=........"
"119","23:39:53.160277","0.000001000","1500","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:16","Htc_9b:92:24","802.11","QoS Data, SN=3447, FN=0, Flags=.p....F."
"120","23:39:53.160290","0.000013000","28","Htc_9b:92:24 (ac:37:43:9b:92:24) (TA)","HuaweiTe_3a:d0:1a (8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a) (RA)","802.11","802.11 Block Ack, Flags=........"
```

Comment: You would *at least* have to post a meaningful sample of such a CSV file.

Comment: @Tomalak https://fil.email/8wSH9ohq Thanks I have now added a csv file

Comment: Add a meaningful sample (10 lines or so), right to your post above, instead of a link to the full 60+ Kb file on an external site. When that link goes dead, it's gonna be useless again.

Answer (score 1):

The csv module is enough here. You just have to read every file one line at a time. If the 8 first characters of the Time field (second one) are the same as the ones of the previous row, then copy the row in the same output file, else create a new output file.

It can be coded as:

```
import os
import csv
startdir='.'
suffix='.csv'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startdir):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(suffix):
            filename=os.path.join(root,name)
            with open(filename) as fd:        # open the csv file
                rd = csv.reader(fd)           #  as a csv input file
                old = None                    # no previous line
                i = 0                         # we will start numbering output files with 1
                header = next(rd)             # store the header line
                for row in rd:
                    if row[1][:8] != old:     # we have a different second (or the first one...)
                        old = row[1][:8]      # store current time for next rows
                        i += 1                # increase output file number
                        if old is not None:   # eventually close previous output file
                            fdout.close()
                        fdout = open(filename[:-4] + str(i) + filename[-4:],
                                 'w', newline='')     # open a new output file
                        wr = csv.writer(fdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)  # with expected csv params
                        _ = wr.writerow(header)   # write the header
                    _ = wr.writerow(row)      # copy the row to the current output file
                fdout.close()
```

---

Above code uses the fact that a second can be determined without parsing directly in the Time string. If you need variable duration eventually smaller that the second, you need to parse the time string and convert it to a decimal (of more exactly floating point) number of seconds and divide it by the choosen duration in seconds:

```
...
sec_duration=0.5     # for half a second
                ...
                for row in rd:
                    # convert the Time field to a total number of seconds in day
                    #  as a flot
                    cur = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[1], "%H:%M:%S.%f")
                    cur -= cur.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
                    # make it a number of periods of sec_duration
                    cur = int(cur.total_seconds() / sec_duration)
                    if cur != old:     # we have a different period (or the first one...)
                        if old is not None:   # eventually close previous output file
                            fdout.close()
                        old = cur      # store current time for next rows
                        i += 1                # increase output file number
                ...
```

Comment: Using the `glob` module would simplify the OS walk and filtering.

Comment: @Serge Thanks. But if I want to split by 0.5 seconds. Then at which line should I do the changes in the code?

Comment: @user3535695: it will be slightly more complex because in addition to the 8 first characters of the time field, you will have to considere the 10th one: if less that 5 you are in the lower part of a second, if at 5 or above in the upper one.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thank you. I am really new to programming, so sorry about these questions. The problem is I have to split the files into different time intervals. for example 1sec, 0.5sec, 0.05 sec, 2 sec etc. I was wondering if its possible to write a python script, that will allow me to input the time value I want (eg:0.5) and based on 'Time' column it will separate the packets that arrived in first 0.5 (according to above sample 23:39:52.634388 to  23:39:53.134388 ) into one file so on?

Comment: I really don't know how to write this :/

Comment: The problem, is that it will work for splitting at 0.5 but it is not the way to go if you later want to split on a different deltatime. Do you want *exactly* 0.5 seconds, or do you need a configurable duration?

Comment: wireshark editcap tool does this task. but it won't accept any values less than 1 second. thats the problem. https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/master/editcap.c

Comment: @SergeBallesta Not exactly 0.5 seconds. I have to try different values. And have to check which time interval gives the best results. So I prefer a code that allow me to try different time values (in seconds).

Comment: @user3535695: Then I have to use a different approach. I should come back here in a while...

Comment: @user3535695: It should now accept a variable duration

Comment: @ thanks. I will try that. sorry for being stupid. can you please tell me what are the code lines that I have to remove from the first code you have written , so I know where to insert your new lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. This will split your sample csv into 11 different files. I suggest creating a test directory and test with the code below if it does what you want it to do.

```
import os
# pandas to read / write csv and process the data
import pandas as pd
startdir='.'
suffix='.csv'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startdir):
  for name in files:
    if name.endswith(suffix):
      filename=os.path.join(root,name)
      #print(filename)
      df = pd.read_csv(filename) 
      # Extract the time for grouping
      col_time = pd.to_datetime(dat1['Time'])
      # Group the values according to second(minute might be not needed)
      df2 = df.groupby([col_time.dt.second,col_time.dt.minute]) 
      # now split the data frame according to group and put them in a list
      list_of_df = [df2.get_group(x) for x in df2.groups]
      # get the data frame from the list and write them 
      for i in range(len(list_of_df)):
        list_of_df[i].to_csv(file_nme[:-4]+str(i)+".csv")
```

Comment: Thank you. where  should I put the split time (eg: if I want to split the packets in 1 second or 2 millisecond time interval) ?

Comment: I assumed that you are splitting table based on the time column inside the table. Thus this line tells how to group the table  `df2 = df.groupby([col_time.dt.second]) `. Did I understand right?

Comment: Pandas is overkill here, because no processing is involved except comparison for one single field with the previous one.

Comment: That's a fair assessment and I agree this might not be the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: yes I have to split based on time column. so the line df2 = df.groupby([col_time.dt.second]) I have to change as  df2 = df.groupby([0.5]) if I want to split by 0.5 seconds? is it correct? Thanks